# It seems that there is no verb is this sentence, "tea in Europe sold for ten times the price of coffee"?

Tags: grammar

This video (https://youtu.be/LaLvVc1sS20?t=168) says

> By 1700, tea in Europe sold for ten times the price of coffee
>   and the plant was still only grown in China.

there is no verb is this sentence, "tea in Europe sold for ten times the price of coffee", is it necessary to rewrite this as follow?

> "tea in Europe was sold for ten times the price of coffee"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb is sold.  It is the past tense of "sell".

We can say "Tea sells for more than coffee" because sell is an ergative verb.

Comment: Some examples might be useful: A: “What do you think of the twins?
B(i): “I approve, they kiss well.” Intransitive = have the ability to kiss well. OR
B(ii): “I approve, they kiss well.” Transitive absolute, i.e. an object can be implied – They kiss anybody well OR
B (iii): “I approve, they kiss well.” = Transitive, reciprocal  = they kiss each other well OR
B (iv): “I approve, they kiss well.” = Anticausative/inchoative/or ergative intransitive = They are pleasant to kiss.